# Husky vs Labrador retriever

Tags: rimworld

[Husky](http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Husky) vs [Labrador retriever](http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Labrador_retriever)
Which animal should i use? Which is better suited for hauling, rescue and other colony chores.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TLDR:** It doesn't matter to much. They are both very good. **But Husky is slightly better.**

If you check their stats you will find out that they are both almost identical. They have the same Wildness ration of 0% - so they are both trained fast. Also they can do the same things.

Only differences:

[image: difference table]

As you can see Husky has better 3 stats. Labrador doesn't have anything better than Husky.

[image: ingame stats]

Tested with A16

Answer (score 2):

RimWorld A18 is mostly the same:
[image]